# Load a video from an Open File Dialog in LiveCode

Tags: video, openfiledialog, livecode

I am doing a video player with LiveCode 7.1.0. I created menu that contains an Open File Dialog. The problem is that I can show the dialog but can't load, in the player, the video the user selected. How can I do this?

EDIT: I have tried the folowing script with a button:

`set the filename of player "DVideoPlayer" to "/Users/1440004/Movies/10.mov"`

and it worked fine. I did the following code for the open option of my menu:

`on menuPick pWhich
  switch pWhich
  case "Ouvrir..."
     answer file "Veuillez choisir une vidéo..." with type ("Tous les vidéos|*|*")
     break
put it into tFile
if tFile is not empty then 
  -- An empty value means that the user pressed cancel. 
  -- We don't want the current player content to be 
  -- lost, so we only change the filename value when 
  -- tFile is not empty.
  set the filename of player "DVideoPlayer" to tFile
end if
  case "Fermer"
   close this stack
  end switch
end menuPick`

and it doesn't work.

Could the problem be when the video player try to get the informations of the "it" variable (convert to tFile) or I didn't place the code at the good place?

Answer (score 0):

This short script asks the user to select a video and loads it in the player. If you want to use a different player, then use a different number of refer to it by name.

```
answer file "Select a video..."
if it is not empty then
  set the filename of player 1 to it
  set the currentTime of player 1 to 0
end if
```

Comment: Sorry but the script didn't work. The video player object is named "Player". When I test the open file dialog I can select a file and clic on open but then nothing append. What I did wrong?

Comment: Didn't you even get an error message? It is confusing to call a player "Player". LiveCode could parse this incorrectly. Give the player a different name, change the script accordingly, and try again. Post the exact text of the error if you get any.

Comment: What is the format of the video you're trying to load?

Comment: A ".mp4" file. Is there some file that are not support like ".flv"?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there is an improvement that can be made to this answer.

As mentioned above it may be that the video selected is one that the player can't play.  I am assuming you are using a Mac.  Over the years and the iterations of Mac OSX versions and Quicktime some .mov movies or .mp4 movies that once would play on a Mac are not playable  on a Mac any more.  (This may be true for windows too but I haven't used LiveCode with Windows much.)

The best way to check if that is the issue is try to open the video in the Quicktime Player on your Mac.  If it doesn't open there then it is a Quicktime Compatability issue.  You will have to convert your movie.

If you want the user to only be able to select video files that can be played you can the specify the type of file to enable on the file selection dialog.  So on a Mac you can specify QuickTime videos or MPEG 4 videos

```
answer file "Veuillez choisir une vidéo..." with type "Quicktime Movie files|mov|Moov" or type "MPEG 4 Movie Files|mp4,m4v|mpg4"
```

This will make a pop up menu on the file opening dialog two items "Quicktime Movie Files" and "MPEG 4 Movie Files"

The rest of the code is correct.

```
put it into tFile
if tFile is not empty then 
  set the filename of player "DVideoPlayer" to tFile
end if
```

Hope you got the answer solved.

Martin